# How to delete TD's using id in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I'm having table generating dynamically using jquery each loop,

each TD is having unique id,

My aim is: when i click on delete button which is out side the loop, has to delete some particular TD's and also empty data for that particular TD.

**HTML  CODE :**

```
<a class='class_removeButton' id="removeUnsupportedFiles" href='javascript:undefined;'>Remove Unsupported Files</a>
```

**JQUERY CODE WORKING FINE WITH INDIVIDUAL DELETE, how to delete tds for some ids :**

```
var upfiles = [{
    name: "name1"
}, {
    name: "name2"
}, {
    name: "name3"
}, {
    name: "name4"
}, {
    name: "name5"
}, {
    name: "name6"
}, {
    name: "name7"
}

];

var int_loop = 1;
var flag_tr = 1;
$('#total').append("<table width=100%>");

$(upfiles).each(function (index, file) {
    display_removebutton = "<img width='20px' style='cursor:pointer;' height='20px' class='class_remove' data-id='" + int_loop + "' id='remove_" + int_loop + "' src='images/DeleteRed.png' />";
    if (flag_tr === 1 && int_loop === 1) {
        $('#total table').append("<tr>");
    } else if (flag_tr === 6) {
        $('#total table').append("<tr>");
    }
    $('#total tr:last').append("<td class='div_files' id='div_selec" + int_loop + "'><b>File Name :</b>" + file.name + display_removebutton + "</td>");
    if (flag_tr === 6) {
        $('#total').append("</tr>");
        flag_tr = 1;
    }
```

//UPDATED CODE STARTS

```
$("#removeUnsupportedFiles").click(function() {
//                        alert(upfiles.length)
//                        flag_extFileBulk = file.name.split(".").pop();
//                        flag_extFileBulk = flag_extFileBulk.toLowerCase();
//                        flag_extCheckBulk = arr_exts.indexOf(flag_extFileBulk);
//                        if(flag_extCheckBulk < 0)
//                        {
//                            upfiles.splice(index, 1);
//                            var $td = $(this).closest('td');
//                            $td.fadeOut(1000,function(){ $td.remove(); });
//                            var $successMessageDiv = $('#div_successLog'); // get the reference of the div
//                            $successMessageDiv.fadeIn('slow').html("Successfully Removed."+ file.name); // show and set the message
//                             $successMessageDiv.fadeOut(1000)
//                             total_size = total_size - (file.size/1024);
//                            if(total_size < limit) 
//                            {
//                                $("#div_errorLog").fadeOut('slow');
//                            }
//                        }
//                    });
```

//UPDATED CODE ENDS

```
    int_loop++;
    flag_tr++;
});
$('#total').on('click', '[id^=remove_]', function () {
    var $td = $(this).closest('td');
    $td.fadeOut(function () {
        $td.remove();
    });
});
```

**Here is the JS FIDDLE : [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dXwR8/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('body').on('click','.class_removeButton',function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZp5z/)**

**Update:** for iterating over unsupported file id arrays and remove them:

```
$.each(deleteRecordIds, function(id, index) {
  $('#'+id).parent().remove()
})
```

Comment: it shoud not remove all the td's, say assume that, i will pass some ids(TD id's) in each loop, only those TD's should get removed

Comment: how are you looping through them. share the code. i will modify accordingly.

Comment: please check my updated code.. there we need to modify var $td = $(this).closest('td');
//                            $td.fadeOut(1000,function(){ $td.remove(); });

Comment: @prassu: what do you want to modify. it looks like you are trying to fadeout and remove the elements parent td??

Comment: what to do you mean by parent td? Hmm see what i need to do is, all the files which are deleting in the updated code has some ids, so only those ids should get deleted, generally im deleting all the unsupported files at one go

Comment: they will come dynamically, they are not fixed, you can see the **<td class='div_files' id='div_selec" + int_loop + "** ids will come from here

Comment: and how are you going o differentiate which all are unsupported?? i have updated the answer, pass the array of ids `deleteRecordIds` and everything should fall in place